# macOS store sandbox app uses NSOpenPanel to select download file folder, but can not access the folder again

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

My app is to download file from a web site.

I enabled the sandbox of the project for macOS store.

[image]

The app will trigger the NSOpenPanel to ask user select the folder where the download files(all file list store in a sqlite file) are saved to.
for example:

```
/home/mymac/myfolder
```

Everything is OK. If I close the app and reopen it, I hope it can be continue to download the files (in the sqlite file).

but it reports error:
   setting security information: Operation not permitted

it looks like the system does not allow the app access the folder

```
/home/mymac/myfolder
```

again.

If I use NSOpenPanel to select the system download folder

```
/home/mymac/Downloads
```

close the app and reopen the app, everything works fine.
It looks like the system only allow the app access the folder

```
/home/mymac/Downloads
```

again.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain a bookmark to the URL and store it persistently. When your application opens, retrieve the URL from the stored bookmark.

The way to do it is described in docs: [Locating Files Using Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10)

You need only 2 methods:

```
- (NSData*)bookmarkForURL:(NSURL*)url
- (NSURL*)urlForBookmark:(NSData*)bookmark
```

You can store the bookmark in a `.plist` file or even in UserDefaults if you don't expect to have lots of bookmarks.

Comment: thanks, my problem is not for the url, it is  that the download folder can not be reopen or accessed again

Comment: Yes, I get it. Whatever you get from the NSOpenPanel, you need to store it as a bookmark to have access on next launch. It might be the Downloads folder, whatever.

Comment: Another approach is to store the files you need in your app's directory. You always have access to it. For example: `let downloads = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .localDomainMask).first`

Comment: app's directory can not be allowed to store users files, Apple has rejected my app which did as this way

Comment: I used NSString to store the folder, I also try NSURL NSData to store the info, nothing change, same error when relaunch app and access the same folder 'cannot open file at line 42249 os_unix.c:42249: (0) - Undefined error: 0'

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16 I am reading this, Security-Scoped Bookmark is the way I need

Comment: @ julia_v Thanks a lot

Comment: `FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first` returns a specific folder, that is meant for you to use. It will be sth like `file:///Users/[username]/Library/Containers/com.SwiftSandboxedTest/Data/Downloads/` Glad if I helped.

Comment: I got it, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can use secure bookmarks for this. I have attached the class that I am using:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

public class SecureFolders
{
    public static var window: NSWindow?

    private static var folders = [URL : Data]()
    private static var path: String?

    public static func initialize(_ path: String)
    {
        self.path = path
    }

    public static func load()
    {
        guard let path = self.path else { return }

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
        {
            return
        }

        if let rawData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        {
            let data = Data(referencing: rawData)

            if let folders = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [URL : Data]
            {
                for folder in folders
                {
                    self.restore(folder)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static func remove(_ url: URL)
    {
        folders.removeValue(forKey: url)
    }

    public static func store(url: URL)
    {
        guard let path = self.path else { return }

        do
        {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.folders, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            self.folders[url] = data

            if let url = URL(string: path)
            {
                try? data.write(to: url)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Swift.print("Error storing bookmarks")
        }
    }

    public static func restore(_ folder: (key: URL, value: Data))
    {
        let restoredUrl: URL?
        var isStale = false

        do
        {
            restoredUrl = try URL.init(resolvingBookmarkData: folder.value, options: NSURL.BookmarkResolutionOptions.withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
        }
        catch
        {
            Swift.print("Error restoring bookmarks")
            restoredUrl = nil
        }

        if let url = restoredUrl
        {
            if isStale
            {
                Swift.print ("URL is stale")
            }
            else
            {
                if !url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                {
                    Swift.print ("Couldn't access: \(url.path)")
                }

                self.folders[url] = folder.value
            }
        }
    }

    public static func allow(folder: String, prompt: String, callback: @escaping (URL?) -> ())
    {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.directoryURL = URL(string: folder)
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.prompt = prompt

        openPanel.beginSheetModal(for: self.window!)
        {
            result in

            if result == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK
            {
                let url = openPanel.url
                self.store(url: url!)

                callback(url)
            }
            else
            {
                callback(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    public static func isStored(_ directory: Directory) -> Bool
    {
        return isStored(path: IO.getDirectory(directory))
    }

    public static func remove(_ directory: Directory)
    {
        let path = IO.getDirectory(directory)
        self.remove(path)
    }

    public static func remove(_ path: String)
    {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        self.remove(url)
    }

    public static func isStored(path: String) -> Bool
    {
        let absolutePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).path

        for url in self.folders
        {
            if url.key.path == absolutePath
            {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    public static func areStored(_ directories: [Directory]) -> Bool
    {
        for dir in directories
        {
            if isStored(dir) == false
            {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    public static func areStored(_ paths: [String]) -> Bool
    {
        for path in paths
        {
            if isStored(path: path) == false
            {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fileprivate func initialize() // Put a call to this in func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let path = directories[0].appending("/SecureBookmarks.dict")

    SecureFolders.initialize(path)
    SecureFolders.load()
}
```

To add a folder to the secure bookmarks:

```
fileprivate func allow(_ path: String)
{
    SecureFolders.allow(folder: path, prompt: "Open")
    {
        result in
        // Update controls or whatever
    }
}
```

Do not forget to set the window instance that is required for the `NSOpenPanel` to be shown. You can set the instance in the `viewDidAppear` of one of your NSViewControllers:

```
override func viewDidAppear()
{
    super.viewDidAppear()
    SecureFolders.window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow
}
```

Comment: thanks, my problem is not for the url, it is  that the download folder can not be reopen or accessed again